# Are seasonal differencing and polynomial trends interchangeable?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend, unit-root

Even though the title suggests just a simple question, it's a two-part.

First, can a repeated seasonal differencing filter also remove a polynomial trend? In which conditions? I would guess only when the degree of the trend is a multiple of the lag used in the filter.

Second, are both the seasonal differencing and the simple (repeated) differencing interchangeable? Is working with a time series by first taking out the trend and then seasonality the same as working with a t.s. by first taking out the seasonality and then the trend?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You asked "how do you distinguish between a deterministic linear trend, and a stochastic trend? Thanks ;) – An old man in the sea. Nov 26 at 22:07" . My answer is simple you approach model formulation in a universal way by evaluating/testing alternative/competing strategies and assess optimality via MAPEs form many origins for different lead times and general effectiveness in dealing/explaining/characterizing the observed history while being concerned with parsimony and sufficiency.

Answer (score 5):

I do not have general answers, but here are some thoughts that will hopefully be helpful.

> First, can a repeated seasonal differencing filter also remove a polynomial trend? In which conditions? I would guess only when the degree of the trend is a multiple of the lag used in the filter.

A simple example of seasonal integration with a seasonal period $m$  is a series made up of $m$ alternating independent random walks. That is, take random walks $x_{1,t},\dots,x_{m,t}$ and form a series $y_{\tau}$ of the form
$$
x_{1,1},\dots,x_{m,1},x_{1,2},\dots,x_{m,2},x_{1,3},\dots,x_{m,3},\dots .
$$
A seasonally differenced process then will be 
$$
\Delta x_{1,2},\dots,\Delta x_{m,2},\Delta x_{1,3},\dots,\Delta x_{m,3},\dots
$$
where $\Delta x_{i,t}:=x_{i,t}-x_{i,t-1}$. So seasonal differencing applied on $y_{\tau}$ is equivalent to simple differencing applied on the alternating component series. The same is true for higher-order seasonal differencing of $y_{\tau}$ vs. higher-order simple differencing of the component series. So from this point on we can consider simple differencing of the component series instead of seasonal differencing of the original series.

If $x_{i,t}$ has a linear trend, $\Delta x_{i,t}$ will no longer have it.
If $x_{i,t}$ has a quadratic trend, $\Delta x_{i,t}$ will have a linear one, but $\Delta^2 x_{i,t}$ will have none.
And so on for higher-order polynomial trends vs. higher-order differencing.

> Second, are both the seasonal differencing and the simple (repeated) differencing interchangeable?

No, they are not intechangeable.
Consider the setup presented above.
*Seasonal* differencing only involves simple differencing of the alternating component series. Therefore, $x_{i,s}$ never gets "mixed up" (i.e. added to or subtracted from) $x_{j,t}$, where $i\neq j$. The different component series remain separated, and a seasonal difference of $y_{\tau}$ of order $D$ can be written as an alternating sequence of simple differences of order $D$ of the component series.
Meanwhile, *simple* differencing of $y_{\tau}$ "mixes up" the component series: you get values like $x_{2,1}-x_{1,1},\dots,x_{m,1}-x_{m-1,1},x_{1,2}-x_{m,1},x_{2,2}-x_{1,2},\dots,x_{m,2}-x_{m-1,2},x_{1,3}-x_{m,2},x_{2,3}-x_{1,3},\dots,x_{m,3}-x_{m-1,3}$ etc. I do not think you could "unmix" the components by taking higher order simple differences, it would rather go the other way around -- you would be involving even more different series (up to a point where all series are involved, of course).

> Is working with a time series by first taking out the trend and then seasonality the same as working with a t.s. by first taking out the seasonality and then the trend?

I guess it depends on how exactly you are doing this. Algebraically this is certainly possible; you can always write $(x_t+s_t)+t=(x_t+t)+s_t$ where $s_t$ stands for the seasonal component and $t$ for a linear time trend. But when you try to achieve this using a particular model being estimated on some data, the equivalence (or lack thereof) between the fitted values of the seasonal and the trend components will depend on the model.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. After I posted this question, I continued reading the notes of Van der Vaart on Time Series. In section 1.2., exercise 1.24, he asks us to prove that filtering is commutative. But isn't differencing a linear filter?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, I missed this comment initially. I don't know how to prove that filtering is commutative or whether differencing is a linear filter (because I don't remember the definition of a linear filter).

Comment: if it is linear - depends on what is differenced, I suppose according to [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/14435) answer

Answer (score 0):

Seasonal differencing is applied once to remove a cyclical component.  This would not remove a polynomial trend such as a linear or a quadratic trend. First differencing is used to remove a linear trend.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? Your answer seems imprecise...

Comment: First differencing should not be used to eliminate a *linear* trend. It would get rid of the trend but at the same time introduce an integrated MA(1) component. Meanwhile, first differencing is to be used for removing a *stochastic* trend.

Comment: @RichardHardy how do you distinguish between a deterministic linear trend, and a stochastic trend? Thanks ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, a linear trend is literally linear, while a stochastic trend is some realization of a random walk (which you could simulate a number of times and see for yourself how it could look). They do not look alike. Or are you asking for some kind of formal test to be applied on a given time series to discover linear or stochastic trends?

Comment: @RichardHardy I was asking for a formula. In this case it would help to describe the concepts.

Comment: A process with a stochastic trend: $y_t=x_t+\varepsilon_t$ where $\varepsilon_t$ is a stationary process and $x_t=\sum_{\tau=0}^t u_{\tau}$ where $u_{\tau}$ is an i.i.d. sequence; i.e., $x_t$ is a random walk. Meanwhile, a process with a linear trend: $z_t=\beta t+\varepsilon_t$.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for your comment. By the way, did you read my other comment, but this time to your answer?

Comment: Please merge your two new accounts http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/140029/michael-chernick and http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/140026/michael-chernick

Comment: Michael, it seems to me that seasonal differencing would remove linear trends in any series, because if we write the series in the form $x_t = \alpha+\beta t+r_t$ for a series $(r_t)$ without linear trends, then $$x_{t+s}-x_t=\beta s +(r_{t+s}-r_t)$$ exhibits the lag-$s$ differences (for a seasonality of lag $s$) as the sum of a constant $\beta s$ plus differences of a trendless series.  Could you therefore provide more detailed justification for your assertions in this reply?

Comment: The merging was done a long time ago (i.e. last month). I think the questions are difficult to answer.  I was thinking in the realm of ARIMA models  where seasonal differencing removes period trends and first differencing removes linear trends.  I think I was trying to show that these two things are not interchangeable.  You introduced a second series in your example.  I wouldn't have that in the model.. Also the trends are stochastic and not deterministic.

Comment: The only thing I think can be said with certainty is that my original deleted answer "The answer to both questions is no".